# PHP: Why strtotime conversion give different values and only limited to a particular date?

Tags: php, centos, strtotime, opensuse

I have two web servers with different operating system.

**SERVER 1** run in Centos 5 with LAMP Server. PHP Version 5.3.21

**SERVER 2** run in openSUSE 11.3 with LAMP Server. PHP Version 5.3.5

Both PHP Configurations are same. Some are the default.

I have a php file with code like this:

```
<?php
/* TEST STRTOTIME */
echo "<br /><br />".strtotime("2038-01-01");
echo "<br /><br />".strtotime("2039-01-01");
?>
```

When i run this file in **SERVER 1**, the result is :

> 2145934800
>
> 2177470800

but when i run this file in **SERVER 2**, the second conversion does not produce anything. Only show result is :

> 2145891600

Why the results of the conversion on both servers give different values​​? whereas the same file. Why on **SERVER 2** could not convert on the above date **2038-01-01**? Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: what happens if you supply the time as well... Might be the default time settings of the os. why the second argument fails is lost on me...

Comment: ...could it be the timezone settings? I know that sometimes it makes a lot of havoc if 2 servers have a different php.ini timezone settings. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your remote server is probably 32-bit. You will need to have a 64-bit server to process dates [after *roughly* 2038](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

The reason is your remote server stores its integers as signed 32 bit integers. The maximum number that can be stored as a signed 32 bit integer is `2,147,483,647` (`2^31 - 1`). Since this number is the number of seconds after Jan 1st, 1970 (Unix epoch), you can see that the number will eventually be exhausted (and possibly overflow if not bounds checked).

[image: Example]

Image Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

Comment: In other words, I need to replace the openSUSE 32-bit to 64-bit? Can upgrade directly from 32-bit to 64-bit without re-install?

Comment: @Fredy Not sure. Alternatively, you could use BC math functions.

Comment: This is most probably the reason but the solution does not necessarily involve installing a new operating system

Comment: @Phil Yeah, swapping an OS isn't too light-weight a job ;)

Comment: @Phil : Thank you. It seems I must reinstall the OS.

Comment: @Fredy If [Phil's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15778931/31671) works for you, consider doing it. It's much easier than changing your OS.

Answer (score 4):

From the [manual for `DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php)

> The date and time information is internally stored as a 64-bit number so all conceivably useful dates (including negative years) are supported. The range is from about 292 billion years in the past to the same in the future.

Also, `strtotime()` has too many inconsistencies to be reliable. I would *always* recommend using `DateTime` instead.

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2039-01-01');
echo $dt->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Drive-by downvoter, care to comment? `DateTime` objects use an internal 64bit number, thus avoiding any operating system limitations

Answer (score 0):

You can check the timezones of your servers.

Also you can set a default timezone using the `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');` command.

Hope this helps.